# Is there any way to work with a users local (non-BIM360) file using design automation and still get things like user selection?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to use the design automation API to modify a Revit file in place. From what I am reading, it seems like, because you have to upload a revit model to the cloud, that there is no way to modify a single users revit model that they have open on thier local Revit client unless the model they are operating on is on BIM360 or another cloud service already.

I would like to make all of my Revit addins into web services to avoid having to manage versioning and distribution of installers for my addins, but it seems that there is no way to make Design Automation API work on a local file that a user has open and modify it in place.

I would also need the ability to get information about what the user is currently selecting in the model to make some of these addins work.

Could anyone shed some light as to whether what I'm asking is possible with Forge in any way or if its just a pipe dream for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, just as you have already noted, the Forge environment in mainly oriented towards viewing CAD files.

The Design Automation API adds the possibility to programmatically modify them in fully automated batch mode.

In all cases, however, the CAD engine is used to manipulate the seed CAD file, in this case the Revit BIM.

For all end user interaction with and modification of the Revit model, you will still be making use of a standard Revit end user installation on the Windows desktop.

You can certainly modify your add-ins to run fully automated in the Forge Design Automation environment.

However, they will not be able to execute on locally stored Revit models in place.

I hope this clarifies.